# Adding "making" at the beginning of a sentence that starts with "even small changes"

Tags: meaning, difference

> A.  **Even small changes** in a company require updating equipment.
>
> B. **Making** even small changes in a company requires the updating of equipment.

Is there any subtle difference in meaning between **A.** and **B.**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a subtle difference.  By adding the "making," you draw emphasis to the action/mechanism of change rather than the changes themselves.  This puts the cause/fault of updates more on the agents of change (for example a board decision) instead of the changes themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The first implies that after a change is made, equipment must be updated; the changes make updating necessary.

The second implies that you must update equipment before you *can* make a change; the action of making a change requires updating.